# How to bind checkbox value to Knockout observableArray on an object?

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have something like this:

```
var ScheduleDay = function(day, times) {
    var self = this;
    self.day = ko.observable(day || "");
    self.times = ko.observableArray(times || []);
};

function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.schedule = ko.observableArray([
        new ScheduleDay("Monday"),
        new ScheduleDay("Tuesday"),
        new ScheduleDay("Wednesday"),
        new ScheduleDay("Thursday"),
        new ScheduleDay("Friday"),
        new ScheduleDay("Saturday"),
        new ScheduleDay("Sunday")
    ])
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

<input id="mondaySchedule" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked ???">
```

I have 3 checkboxes for each day of the week: morning, afternoon, and evening. I would like a model that is something like: schedule:{Monday:["morning","afternoon"], Tuesday: ["afternoon"], etc.}

Comment: The checkbox is intended to store binary value (true/false, yes/no) or one value in a set. Your `times` property initialy contains an empty array so there is no sense to bind this observable to checkboxes. Could you supply more details about what you want to get?

Comment: Why one value in a set? Wouldn't that be more for radio buttons? I have 3 checkboxes for each day of the week: morning, afternoon, and evening. I would like a model that is something like:

schedule:{Monday:["morning","afternoon"], Tuesday: ["afternoon"], etc.}

Comment: Yeah, each checkbox will present only one value of given three. See my answer.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this (crucial) information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have specified your question in comments, I suggest to take a look at this simple markup, that will do what you want:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: schedule">
    <li>
        <strong data-bind="text: day"></strong>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: times" value='morning' /> Morning
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: times" value='afternoon' /> Afternoon
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: times" value='evening' /> Evening
    </li>
</ul>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qjzbossb/